# Weird execution behaviour of fork() method

Tags: operating-system, fork

I wrote a simple example of `fork()` like below:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
void main()
{

        printf("Stack overflow\n");
        pid_t p = fork();
        if ( p )
            printf("I am parent\n");
        else
            printf("I am child\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Ideally, "Stack overflow" should be printed only once but at my end the string is printed twice. I am unable to understand it. Can anyone help?

Comment: You might want to add `#includes` at the top of this. I'm presuming you use `unistd.h` (for fork) and `stdio.h` (for printf), but there might be other implementations you use, and these of course could change behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a flushing problem: Your program is running just fine, but the output of the first `printf` is only handed over to the standard output after the `fork` has happened.

Try

```
fflush(stdout);
```

before forking. It fixes this.